# Pandas Group By Cumulative Sum

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataset that has total sales and unit price. I'd like to add a new column that flags each group based on each $100 worth of sales. Some orders have already been fulfilled, so I'd like to ignore these.

Is it possible to create a running total, and then add a column with a label that shows every group of orders with a limit of 100 per order?

Context: Imagine that you have a table where people are adding orders to as line items... 1 order of x amount of Product A ends up being $350.

We have a constraint where we can only process the orders in groups under $10,000, so we are looking to process as many line items as possible within that allotted $10,000. Sometimes that would be 1 order (line item), sometimes 2, 3, 4, etc.

[image]

Comment: Can you please add some relevant code snippets

Comment: @JayVasant - attached a table with the data and desired output as the "Group" Column